# angularJS ui-routing the admin dashboard is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**INITIAL PROBLEM**

My initial goal was to create a login page outside of the admin dashboard for my angularJS app. the Problem I was having was that login page was always included in the admin dashboard skeleton since it is a single page application and the dashboard skeleton is in index.html

**SOLUTION 1**

Someone suggested ui routing to me, so I used it and was able to create a login page and an admin dashboard.

**SOLUTION 1 PROBLEM**

Now the problem that I am having is that the admin dashboard does not work well when navigating. Because the admin dashboard header and sidebar was supposed to be a skeleton to the pages I navigate through. However I am not sure how to set it up that way again. It initially worked because admin dashboard header and sidebar was part of the index.html, now it is part of the header.html template.

This is my **routes.js** code:

```
angular.module('RDash').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {



            // Login
            $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: "",
                views: {
                    "viewA": {
                        templateUrl: "templates/login.html"
                    }
                }

            })
            .state('adminDashboard', {     //admin Dashboard
                url: "/adminDashboard",
                views: {
                    "viewA": {
                        templateUrl: "templates/header.html"
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('dashboard', {    //dashboard nav link in admin dashboard
                    url: '/dashboard',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html'
                })
            .state('tables', {      //tables nav link in admin dashboard
                    url: '/tables',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tables.html'
                })
            .state('question', {   //question nav link in admin dashboard
                    url: '/question',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/question.html'
                });
        }
    ]);
```

as you can see, there are two big views, **adminDashboard** and **login**, inside the adminDashboard view, there is a nav bar for the other three routes: dashboard, tables and question

and this is my **index.html** code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="RDash">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Application</title>
  <!-- STYLES -->
  <!-- build:css lib/css/main.min.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/rdash-ui/dist/css/rdash.min.css">
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <!-- build:js lib/js/main.min.js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- Custom Scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dashboard.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
  <!-- NAVBAR FOR LOGIN AND DASHBOARD-->
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" ui-sref="login">Quick Start</a>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="login">login</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="adminDashboard">dashboard</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>Application</h1>
     <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
      <!-- div tag for ui-view-->
      <div class="well" ui-view="viewA"></div>        
    </div>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I created for the index page a navbar to go from login to admin dashboard (Just temporary), and as you can see there is the div tag for **ui-view** that changes by navigating in the **index.html** page

So how do we make the three other routes(Dashboard, tables and question) part of the admin dashboard skeleton again ?

I am not sure if I took the correct approach to accomplish this

Also I hope I am explaining my goal clearly. Please ask and I will update if there is any vagueness in my explanation

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the adminDashboard state as abstract state using the parameter abstract:true

And then you can access other three states using the '.' operator
Eg you want to make 'tables' state as child of adminDashboard so define
tables state as adminDashboard.tables

Comment: Great now it is working, however I added two and only the first nav dashboard button is working

`.state('adminDashboard.dashboard', {
                url: '/:dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'templates/adminDashboard.dashboard.html'
            })
        .state('adminDashboard.tables', {
                url: '/:tables',
                templateUrl: 'templates/adminDashboard.tables.html'
            });`

The second nav(Tables) changes the path but shows me the same view page(dashboard). Can you figure out why ?

Comment: it is not working completely you cant tell what the problem is for second nav button ?

Comment: turns out I need to use **ui-sref** instead of href in the html file. thanks for the help